# Is there a syncronous load bytes method yet for Flash or AIR?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, air

Is there a *synchronous* [loadBytes()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#loadBytes()) method yet in Flash Player or AIR?

**More Info:**
I'm trying to load a byte array and convert it into bitmap data synchronously (NOT ASYNCHRONOUSLY). It cannot be asynchronous. It is PNG that was encoded into base64 data.

Now I'm decoding from base64 into a byte array and then trying to decode that byte array into bitmap data. There is no way to go from byte array to bitmap data without a loader and `loader.loadBytes()` is asynchronous.

I suppose I could pass the byte array to JavaScript if there is a class for that but that's a last resort.

FYI I'm running AIR 23.

It looks like there is a synchronous decoding mentioned [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS52621785137562065a8e668112d98c8c4df-8000.html) but it doesn't seem to work. Well, it seems I still need to add event listeners and wait a frame:

[image]

Let me repeat, it cannot be asynchronous. My question is if it's possible.

Here is my example code to encode my data. I'm using this [call](https://github.com/monkeypunch3/flexcapacitor/blob/master/MainLibrary/src/com/flexcapacitor/utils/DisplayObjectUtils.as#L1493):

```
var base64ImageData:String = DisplayObjectUtils.getBase64ImageDataString(displayObject, DisplayObjectUtils.PNG, null, true);
```

I want to decode it in the next line but `loadBytes()` doesn't seem to allow that. I'm using this [call](https://github.com/monkeypunch3/flexcapacitor/blob/master/MainLibrary/src/com/flexcapacitor/utils/DisplayObjectUtils.as#L1906):

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = DisplayObjectUtils.getBitmapDataFromBase64(bitmapDataString);
```

Let me repeat, I'm looking for a synchronous action. It cannot be asynchronous. My question is if it's possible.

Comment: you mean that you have to continue your code execution strictly after `loader.loadBytes()` is complete?

Comment: Yes. I cannot use async because code directly after it depends on it.

Comment: Why can't it be asynchronous?  That's very fishy -- virtually EVERYTHING in as3 is asynchronous.

Comment: I agree with @Brian. What's so bad about asynchronous decoding of bytes held in device's Ram? Try to explain your real **issue** / **end goal** better otherwise your concern feels redudant.

Comment: _"I'm trying to load a byte array and convert it into bitmap data synchronously"_ So you want however much of total bytes received to be visible? eg: if 50% worth of bytes passed to `loader.loadBytes()` it makes half image? If yes then why involve base64 since that forces you to have the full base64 bytes decoded correctly before you can even extract PNG data from it. Decoding first 10% of base64 does not give first 10% of PNG bytes, so you cannot pass these decoded bytes to `loader` expecting a 10% image....

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Sure it matters.  It's a question that makes me think "Hey, this guy is deep into [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) land".  Same as if you were asking for a synchronous "load URL contents" feature - whatever reason you're looking for it, it's still going to freeze the UI.

Comment: @Brian Of course I don't want to freeze the UI. But in my case I've profiled everything and it's a process that's in a loop. The whole encoding takes a few milliseconds and decoding takes a few milliseconds. The problem is that I don't want to have to setup event listeners and split the whole process into two parts because in this case it doesn't need to be. And doing so requires much more work. I'm into an XY question but I've encountered this before where synchronous is the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

As the [reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#loadBytes()) says:

> complete:Event — Dispatched by the contentLoaderInfo object when the operation is complete. The complete event is always dispatched after the init event.

So you can execute depending code from the `Event.COMPLETE` handler.

Comment: That method is Asynchronous. I'm asking about synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [BitmapData.setPixels()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#setPixels()), which is synchronous. You need 32-bit unmultiplied ARGB values for pixels in the source byte array. Consider printing [BitmapData.getPixels()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getPixels()) from a test image to see the way pixels should be stored.

> Converts a byte array into a rectangular region of pixel data. For each pixel, the ByteArray.readUnsignedInt() method is called and the return value is written into the pixel. If the byte array ends before the full rectangle is written, the function returns. The data in the byte array is expected to be 32-bit ARGB pixel values. No seeking is performed on the byte array before or after the pixels are read.

**UPDATE:** `getBase64ImageDataString()` converts your image to PNG or JPG using either `BitmapData.encode()` (for flash player 11.3 and above), or `mx.graphics.codec.PNGEncoder/JPEGEncoder` classes (from Flex SDK). It then encodes the resulting binary data to base64.

The only format you can use synchronously with `BitmapData.setPixels()` is the one mentioned above: plain rows of ARGB pixels with no header. No PNG, JPG or other formats allowed.

When you use `Loader.loadBytes()`, it does all the heavy lifting, decoding the file header, finding image size, color settings and converting data to internal format. If you really want to convert serialized image data to BitmapData synchronously, you will have to do all that manually. Decode base64 string, get a ByteArray, then use a third-party class to convert image data to pixels in ActionScript. Which will be sub-optimal performance-wise to say the least. Decoders are [easily found on the net](http://heriet.info/as/images/PNGDecoder.as), but I'd consider this a bad idea anyway.

Comment: Hi @NoxNocts. I'll see if I can make this method work. I'm not encoding the data using setPixels() but encoding to base 64 string. I think the problem with this method is that you must set the BitmapData size and you cannot change the size later. I have base 64 bitmap data from the server but base 64 does not have the size.

Comment: Which format does your server use for encoding before serializing image data to base 64?

Comment: I'm encoding the data with this function `getBase64ImageDataString()` https://github.com/monkeypunch3/flexcapacitor/blob/master/MainLibrary/src/com/flexcapacitor/utils/DisplayObjectUtils.as#L1493. I can encode it easily in one line of code but if I want to decode it on the next line I have to use a Loader and wait a frame? I need it all in the same block of code.